# React Native FlatList onEndReached called when end of ListFooterComponent is reached

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a `FlatList` to display a list of items with inifinite scrolling. More data is loaded when the end of the list is reached using the `onEndReached` prop. However, below the list is more content using `ListFooterComponent`. This causes `onEndReached` to be called when the end of the footer is reached, rather than the end of the actual list. It's possible to configure this a bit using `onEndReachedThreshold` but the height of the footer may change regularly so this is not a good solution.

```js
<FlatList
    data={[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
    renderItem={() => (
       <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#f00", height: 300 }} />
    )}
    ListFooterComponent={
       <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#0f0", height: 3000 }} />
    }
    onEndReached={() => console.log("will be called when end of ListFooterComponent is reached")}
/>
```

Is this a bug or should it work like that? Does anybody have an idea for a workaround?

Comment: same here. Did u find a solution?

Comment: No unfortunately not. In my case I figured it doesn't make sense to have that content at the end of a list anyway because you would have to scroll to the end multiple times before you would see it. So it wouldn't be seen by anyone anyway and I ended up just removing the FooterComponent